# MSBuild not creating specified directory

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I need a directory named configuration at

*Src/test.Workflow.UnitTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/Configuration*

I'm trying to create it with MSBuild and here is what I tried

```
<Target Name="WorkflowUnitTests">

    <MakeDir Directories="Src/test.Workflow.UnitTests/bin/$(Configuration)/$(OutputFrameworkVersion)/Configuration"/>

    <MSBuild Projects="Src/test.Workflow.UnitTests/test.Workflow.UnitTests.csproj" Targets="$(BuildTarget)" Condition=" $(Configuration) == 'Debug' ">
    </MSBuild>

    <SyncTask SourceFolder="Src/test.Workflow/Configuration"
              DestinationFolder="Src/test.Workflow.UnitTests/bin/$(Configuration)/$(OutputFrameworkVersion)/Configuration"
              Mirror="true" ExcludeFolders="" ExcludeFiles=""/>

</Target>
```

I can't find a reason for why it's not working as intended. Please enlighten me.

**EDIT :**  For clarafication , here is the properties that I used:

```
<BuildTarget>Build</BuildTarget>

<Configuration>Debug</Configuration>

<OutputFrameworkVersion>netcoreapp3.0</OutputFrameworkVersion>
```

**EDIT2 (Solved) :** I managed to figure out the issue. The problem is that SyncTask command is not working because the DLL file that references SyncTask is compiled in .netcore 2.2 and we are trying to build the project with .netcore 3.0. I rebuilt the DLL file with .netcore3.0 and referenced the newly created one.

All in all, the code I wrote initially was just fine. I wasted my time for not inspecting the problem thoroughly, well deserved. Thanks to you all who tried to help.

Comment: Is WorkflowUnitTests target being called anywhere?

Comment: Only reference is this ``` <Target Name="UnitTest" DependsOnTargets="FrameworkTests;WorkflowUnitTests"> ```  @GazTheDestroyer

Comment: Ok, and presumably "UnitTest" is being called somewhere too as part of "Build" target?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Correct

Comment: So the target is being run ok? (ie UnitTest.csproj is being built?). That would infer that a directory is being created, just not where you think it is. Have you tried debugging to the console. ie `<Message Text="DEBUG DIR CREATE: PATH= Src/test.Workflow.UnitTests/bin/$(Configuration)/$(OutputFrameworkVersion)/Configuration"/>`

Comment: Did you check whether the target `WorkflowUnitTests` runs without any problems? You can see the build output log to check whether the target runs and the state of the folder which you want to create. If you build with VS IDE, you can set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `detailed` by `Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Build and Run`. If you build with MSBuild command, you can add `/verbosity:Detailed` to see the detailed log. Please refer to the build log ,observe the operation of the target and then share the info with us(any error message).

Comment: In addition,  I wonder if there is another target that had an impact on the `WorkflowUnitTests`.